# file rename() function works but also throws error

Tags: php

I'm trying to rename a file, when i call rename() function the file get gets renamed but it still gives me error "The filename uploads/09-12-2015.xls is not readable"

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../../Classes/');
include 'lib/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'connect.php';

if (isset($_POST['config']))
{
    $hotelName = $_POST['shortname'];
    $reportDate = $_POST['reportDate'];
    $dateCol = $_POST['dateCol'];
    $dateRow = $_POST['dateRow'];
    $soldCol = $_POST['soldCol'];
    $revCol = $_POST['revCol'];
    $todayDate = date('m-d-Y');

    rename("uploads/$todayDate.xls","uploads/$reportDate.xls");
    echo "done";
    //$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);  
    //$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that error is coming from `rename`?

Comment: You could try prefixing the `rename` function call with an "@" sign to prevent it displaying an error ~ @rename('from','to')

Comment: it is coming from rename because i commented out rename and error doesn't show.

Comment: just found my own mistake, I'm viewing the that file name on page on different place, so when it gets renamed and page refreshes it complains. sorry about that

Comment: It could be because some later code is trying to access the file with the original name. WHen you rename the file, it can't read it; if you comment out the rename, it works.

Comment: yes thank you, other code was accessing file.